# How to run a bash terminal in a Docker container along with additional commands?

Tags: bash, docker

To run a bash terminal in a Docker container I can run the following:

```
$ docker exec -it <container> /bin/bash
```

However, I want to execute a command in the container automatically. For example, if I want to open a bash terminal in the container and create a file I would expect to run something like:

```
docker exec -it <container> /bin/bash -c "touch foo.txt"
```

However, this doesn't work... Is there a simple way to achieve this? Of course, I could type the command after opening the container, but I want to open a bash terminal and run a command at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run your touch command and then spawn another shell :

```
docker exec -it <container> /bin/bash -c "touch foo.txt; exec bash"
```

Answer (score 2):

Works perfectly fine for me

```
~# docker run -tid --rm --name test ubuntu:20.04
~# docker exec -it test /bin/bash -c "touch /foo.txt"
~# docker exec -it test /bin/bash
root@b6b0efbb13be:/# ls -ltr foo.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  7 05:35 foo.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution:

```
docker exec -it <container> touch foo.txt
```

You can verify

```
docker exec -it <container> ls
```

This was tested with `alpine` image.

Remember that in docker images there is a `entrypoint` and a `command`. Now we are editing the command of the default entrypoint for `alpine`, via `docker exec`

It depends of the entrypoint if env variablers are load or not, `$PATH` ..., so other images maybe you need to write `/bin/touch` or `/usr/bin/ls`

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

When you run `docker exec -it <container> /bin/bash -c "touch foo.txt"`, container sends `0 exit code` so that it means the task is done and you'll be returned to your host.

When you run `docker exec -it <container /bin/bash`, `bash` shell is not terminated until you explicitly type `exit` or use `CTRL+D` in bash environment. `bash` is continuously running.

This is why when you run the second command, it goes to bash, runs your command (touches) and then exits.